# Can I use "Lucir" in the sense of "to wear without being dazzling"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado

I recently came across the following verb "lucir".

> Se puede lucir una tableta de chocolate.

meaning to be able to display or show off a six-pack.

Can this verb also be used for wearing clothes?

> Luces un par de zapatos/pantalones.

I mean in an everyday sense without the sense of looking stunning or dazzling as I think it can imply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can. See the fifth definition or "[lucir](https://dle.rae.es/lucir?m=form)" in the DLE

> 5. tr. Llevar a la vista, exhibir lo que alguien se ha puesto, normalmente como adorno.

and the eighth

> 8. prnl. Vestirse y adornarse con esmero.

So you can definitely say

> Hoy el pelo me luce muy bien

> Luces un bonito par de zapatos nuevos

> Lucía un collar nuevo que le habían regalado

It doesn't necessarily mean "to show off" but "lucir**se**" does mean "to show off" or "to make an impression".